# Ipad app not showing essential information

Tags: feature-request, protected-questions

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348196/how-do-i-enable-ubuntu-using-full-disk-encryption-to-call-lukssupend-before-sl)  is protected. In the iPad app I see it's protected but no reason is shown. In a browser I see it's protected because of low quality answers and a minimum reputation is required to answer. I like to see this additional information in the iPad app too, please.